# how to use the NormalizeChars stored procedure inside the searchWord stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, diacritics

I want to remove the diacritics from this function

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchWord] (@Word            NVARCHAR(50),
                                    @PageNumber      INT,
                                    @ProductsPerPage INT,
                                    @HowManyResults  INT OUTPUT)
AS
  SET @Word = '%' + RTRIM(@Word) + '%';

  DECLARE @Results TABLE (
    ProductsId          INT,
    ProductsCode        NVARCHAR(250),
    ProductsDesc        NVARCHAR(MAX),
    ProductsIngredients NVARCHAR(MAX),
    ProductsName        NVARCHAR(250),
    ProductsPhoto       NVARCHAR(MAX),
    ProductsPrice       MONEY,
    ProductsWeight2     FLOAT,
    RowNumber           INT)

  -- Obtain the matching products
  INSERT INTO @Results
  SELECT DISTINCT T1.ProductsID,
                  T1.ProductsCode,
                  LOWER(T1.ProductsDesc)                      asProductsDesc,
                  T1.ProductsIngredients,
                  LOWER(T1.ProductsName)                      AS ProductsName,
                  T1.ProductsPhoto,
                  T1.ProductsPrice,
                  T1.ProductsWeight2,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T1.ProductsName) RowNumber
  FROM   (SELECT ProductsID,
                 ProductsCode,
                 LOWER(ProductsDesc) AS ProductsDesc,
                 ProductsIngredients,
                 LOWER(ProductsName) AS ProductsName,
                 ProductsPhoto,
                 ProductsPrice,
                 ProductsWeight2
          FROM   Products
          WHERE  ProductsName LIKE @Word) AS T1
         FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT *
                          FROM   Products
                          WHERE  ProductsDesc LIKE @Word) AS T2
           ON T1.ProductsID = T2.ProductsID
  ORDER  BY T1.ProductsPrice

  DELETE FROM @Results
  WHERE  NULLIF([ProductsName], '') IS NULL

  SELECT @HowManyResults = COUNT(*)
  FROM   @Results

  INSERT INTO @Results
  SELECT DISTINCT ProductsId,
                  ProductsCode,
                  ProductsDesc,
                  ProductsIngredients,
                  LOWER(ProductsName) AS ProductsName,
                  ProductsPhoto,
                  ProductsPrice,
                  ProductsWeight2,
                  RowNumber
  FROM   @Results

  SELECT DISTINCT ProductsId,
                  ProductsCode,
                  ProductsDesc,
                  ProductsIngredients,
                  LOWER(ProductsName) AS ProductsName,
                  ProductsPhoto,
                  ProductsPrice,
                  ProductsWeight2,
                  RowNumber
  FROM   @Results R
  WHERE  R.RowNumber > ( @PageNumber - 1 ) * @ProductsPerPage
         AND R.RowNumber <= @PageNumber * @ProductsPerPage
  ORDER  BY R.ProductsPrice ASC
```

using this procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE normalizeChars 
(@NAME NVARCHAR(100)) 
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @TempString NVARCHAR(100)
  SET @TempString = @NAME 
  SET @TempString = LOWER(@TempString)
  SET @TempString =  REPLACE(@TempString,'à', 'a')
  SET @TempString =  REPLACE(@TempString,'è', 'e')
  SET @TempString =  REPLACE(@TempString,'é', 'e')
  SET @TempString =  REPLACE(@TempString,'ì', 'i')
  SET @TempString =  REPLACE(@TempString,'ò', 'o')
  SET @TempString =  REPLACE(@TempString,'ù', 'u')
  SET @TempString =  REPLACE(@TempString,'ç', 'c')
  SET @TempString =  REPLACE(@TempString,'''', '')
  SET @TempString =  REPLACE(@TempString,'`', '')
  SET @TempString =  REPLACE(@TempString,'-', '')
  SET @TempString =  REPLACE(@TempString,'ά','α')
  SET @TempString =  REPLACE(@TempString,'έ','ε')
  SET @TempString =  REPLACE(@TempString,'ί','ι')
  SET @TempString =  REPLACE(@TempString,'ό','ο')
  SET @TempString =  REPLACE(@TempString,'ή','η')
  SET @TempString =  REPLACE(@TempString,'ύ','υ')
  RETURN @TempString
END

on ProductsName and ProductsDesc
```

is it possible and how?

Comment: Instead of removing the diacritics, how about specifying the collation order during the search?

Comment: Your `normalizeChars` procedure would need to be a scalar UDF (Procedures can't return strings like that anyway). But I agree with @Mitch. Won't an Accent Insensitive collate clause work for you?

Comment: how can i specify an accent insensitive collation , i think i have . i allready specified a column colation and i havent checked the accent in the dictionary checkbox..

Comment: It is set at database level and column level. You can also set it explicitly as follows `SELECT * FROM sys.objects where name like N'à%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI`. Edit : So what collation does your column have then? Also what are you trying to do? An Accent Insensitive search - or strip the accents out of the displayed results?

Comment: an accent insensitive search, the colation is Greek_CI_AI, this query returns 0 rows SELECT * FROM sys.objects where name like N'à%' COLLATE Greek_CI_AI

Comment: @ailatzis - For me your query returns all objects beginning with `A` and `a` do you have any such objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you are on `Greek_CI_AI`. In that case most of your mappings already happen (Only the top 3 don't).

```
;WITH T(col1,col2) AS
(
  SELECT N'''',N'' UNION ALL
  SELECT N'`',N'' UNION ALL
  SELECT N'-',N'' UNION ALL

  SELECT N'à',N'a' UNION ALL
  SELECT N'è',N'e' UNION ALL
  SELECT N'é',N'e' UNION ALL
  SELECT N'ì',N'i' UNION ALL
  SELECT N'ò',N'o' UNION ALL
  SELECT N'ù',N'u' UNION ALL
  SELECT N'ç',N'c' UNION ALL
  SELECT N'ά',N'α' UNION ALL
  SELECT N'έ',N'ε' UNION ALL
  SELECT N'ί',N'ι' UNION ALL
  SELECT N'ό',N'ο' UNION ALL
  SELECT N'ή',N'η' UNION ALL
  SELECT N'ύ',N'υ'
)
SELECT *
FROM T 
WHERE col1<>col2  COLLATE Greek_CI_AI
```

Returns

```
col1 col2
---- ----
'    
`    
-
```

Also you don't need to use `LOWER` as the collation is case insensitive.

If you do need to ignore the remaining 3 characters in your search you could use a scalar UDF as below

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.normalizeChars 
(@Name NVARCHAR(100)) 
RETURNS NVARCHAR(100)
WITH SCHEMABINDING, RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS 
BEGIN
  SET @Name =  REPLACE(@Name,'''', '')
  SET @Name =  REPLACE(@Name,'`', '')
  SET @Name =  REPLACE(@Name,'-', '')
  RETURN @Name
END
```

Comment: thank you Martin. I had to delete the full index and set again the collation, now everything is ok